# Find limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln|x|}{x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln|x|}{x}$

I have used a substitution  $\ln|x|=y$

$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{y}{e^y}$

=$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{y}{1+\frac{y}{1!}+\frac{y^2}{2!}..+\frac{y^n}{n!}}$ where n goes to infinity as well.

=$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{y^{n-1}}}{\frac{1}{y^n}+\frac{1}{1!.y^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2!.y^{n-2}}..+\frac{1}{n!}}$

=$\frac{0}{\frac{1}{n!}}$

=$0\times n!$   ----------(A)

=$0$

Since Maclaurin series is infinite 'n' goes to infinity. So in the line (A) can we say this multiplication is zero? If I'm wrong in any other step please correct me.

I prefer not to use L'Hospital.

Comment: Isn't it a high school result?

Comment: indeed this was done at highschool level. But my problem is since n is infinite can we say this product 0xn! tends to zero?

Comment: If you explicitly add the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ that you left out, you'll see that you're exchanging $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ and $\lim_{y \to \infty}$ at the third $=$-sign. You cannot do that without justification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are going to use the Taylor series $e^y=1+\frac{y}{1!}+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\dots$, it is better to say that for $y>0$, $e^y=1+\frac{y}{1!}+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\dots >\frac{y^2}{2!}$, which implies that
$$0<\frac{y}{e^y}< \frac{y}{\frac{y^2}{2!}}=\frac{2}{y}\to 0$$
and THEN we take the limit as $y\to +\infty$ on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

$x>0$;

$\dfrac{\log x}{x}=(1/x)\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{x}}(1/t)dt \le$

$(1/x)\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{x}}(1/t^{1/2})dt =$

$ 2(1/x)(t^{1/2}) \big ]_{1}^{x}= 2(1/x)(x^{1/2}-1) $

$\lt  \dfrac{2}{x^{1/2}}$.

Take the limit.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint.* Prove that for $x>0,$ we have that $$\log x<\sqrt x.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the finite integral $\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy=1!=1$ has a non-negative integrand with unique maximum at $y=1$, the integrand's $y\to\infty$ limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

From your substitution, you can use the fact that the exponential function grows faster than a linear. 
Also,

for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln|x|}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln|x|}{|x|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}$$
By *Stolz-Cesaro* for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$  case (a discrete version of L'Hospital, i.e., you don't derive explicitly):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln (n+1)-\ln n}{(n+1)-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{1}=0$$