# Finding whether $\sum \ln(n)/n^2$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Last one in a series of similar questions to check if I got it.

I solved this by doing

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2} $$

for $0 \le n < 3$. Since $1/n^2$ converges, so does $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$, even if it's only in that range. Is this correct?

Comment: No, the series is not only over $0\le n<3$.

Comment: Silence.Perhaps of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555924/find-limit-of-lim-x-to-infty-frac-lnxx/3555951#3555951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, definitely,

$$
\frac{{\ln n}}
{{n^2 }} \leqslant \frac{{\sqrt n }}
{{n^2 }} = \frac{1}
{{n^{3/2} }}
$$
your series is convergent by direct comparison test

Comment: Why $\sqrt{n}/n^2$?

Comment: $\log n$ grows slower than any root $\sqrt[m]n$ (it is virtually $n^0$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried to prove that by taking the derivatives of $\ln(n)$ and $\sqrt{n}$ and compare and got $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{2x^2}$. This condition is not true... it's not that I doubt you I am just trying to figure out where it went wrong

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: $\frac1{2x^2}$ ???

Comment: The reasons for the choice of $\sqrt n$ are: eventually it is $\log n  < \sqrt n$ and $\sqrt n$ is still quite slow in order to obtain  $1/n^3/2$ which give us a convergent series. You can choose any other power of $n$ not greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. That doesn't make sense, since your goal is to determine whether or not $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ converges.

You can apply the comparison test:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\log n}{n^2}}{n^{-3/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}=0$$and therefore $\frac{\log n}{n^2}\leqslant n^{-3/2}$ if $n$ is large enough. Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3/2}$ converges, then so does your series.